# Listview does no refresh or update after deleting last item on listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have an issue with deleting the last item within my listview. If I have, let's say 3 contacts on the list view, deleting 2 out of the 3 contacts is no problem. The listview will automatically refresh and the 2 out of the 3 contacts will be removed from the list. However, if I were to delete the last and third contact, the listview will not update or refresh unless I exit from the form and re-open it.

Below is my code

```
Private Sub ContactTab_load()
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = Search.sqlConnect
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlTable As New DataTable
    Dim sqlText As String

    nameForm.nameSearch = nameForm.nameListView.SelectedItems(0).Text
    Dim InstitutionContactName As String = nameForm.nameSearch
    InstitutionContactName = InstitutionContactName.Replace("'", "''")

    sqlText = "select c.contact_id, c.contact_first_name,c.contact_last_name,c.primary_phone,c.primary_email, ct.contact_type_name, ihc.institution_id from institution i left outer join institution_has_contact ihc on i.institution_id = ihc.institution_id left outer join contact c on ihc.contact_id = c.contact_id join contact_type ct on ct.contact_type_id = c.contact_type_id where institution_name='" & InstitutionContactName & "' order by contact_first_name"

    If Search.debugging Then
        MsgBox("sql=" & sqlText)
    End If

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlText
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(sqlTable)
    End With

    If sqlTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        InstitutionContactListView.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
            With InstitutionContactListView
                .Items.Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("contact_id"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("contact_first_name"))
                    .Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("contact_last_name"))
                    .Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("primary_phone"))
                    .Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("primary_email"))
                    .Add(sqlTable.Rows(i)("contact_type_name"))
                End With
            End With
        Next
        sqlTable.Dispose()
        sqlCommand.Dispose()
        sqlAdapter.Dispose()
    End If

    If InstitutionContactListView.Items.Count > 0 Then
        InstitutionContactListView.Items(0).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is the code to remove the contacts

```
Private Sub RemoveContactButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RemoveContactButton.Click
    If ContactIDSelected > -1 Then
        RunSql("delete from institution_has_contact where institution_id = " & InstitutionID & " and contact_ID=" & ContactIDSelected)
        ContactTab_load()
    Else
        MsgBox("Select a Contact to be removed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: are you sure it is a ListView?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I named it InstitutionContactListView

Comment: the problem must be inside one of those methods

Comment: If i would to put the code for the loading method for the listview would you be able to identify the issue?

Comment: try putting `InstitutionContactListView.Items.Clear()` before the `If sqlTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then` so that the LV clears when there are no rows as when you delete the last one, OR add an Else that clears the LV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ContactTab_load` procedure does not account for no rows returned from the query:

```
If sqlTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    InstitutionContactListView.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
        With InstitutionContactListView
    ' ...
```

Move the Clear to outside the loop, so that when you delete/remove the last item, the LV is cleared:

```
InstitutionContactListView.Items.Clear()
If sqlTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
        With InstitutionContactListView
    ' ...
```

Alternatively, add an ELSE to do the same.